# What is the most effective way to incremente a large number of values in Python?

Tags: python

Okay, sorry if my problem seems a bit rough. I'll try to explain it in a figurative way, I hope this is satisfactory.

> 10 children.
>  5 boxes.
>  Each child chooses three boxes.
>  Each box is opened:
>   - If it contains something, **all children selected this box gets 1 point**
>   - Otherwise, nobody gets a point.

My question is about what I put in bold. Because in my code, there are lots of kids and lots of boxes.

Currently, I proceed as follows:

```
children = {"child_1" : 0, ... , "child_10": 0}

gp1 = ["child_3", "child_7", "child_10"] #children who selected the box 1
...
gp5 = ["child_2", "child_5", "child_8", "child_10"]

boxes = [(0,gp1), (0,gp2), (1,gp3), (1,gp4), (0,gp5)]

for box in boxes:
    if box[0] == 1: #something inside
        for child in box[1]:
            children[child] += 1
```

I worry mainly about the for loop that assigns each child an extra point. Because in my final code, I have many many children, I fear that doing so would slow the program too.

Is there a more efficient way for all children of the same group may have their point faster?

Comment: It looks reasonably efficient. Do you know it's too slow?

Comment: I guess the whole procedure gets repeated many times. Doe the boxes or the groups change often?

Comment: How many are "many, many children"? One thing you could do is use a `collections.Counter` instead of the `children` dictionary, especially with the way you are initializing it (but you could also use a `dict` comprehension based on a list of children).

Comment: @zch After finally implement my problem, the program put about 0.20 seconds to complete the loop. However, I have to repeat this often, so I need to optimize it.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida Approximately, there are 40,000 children who must select 100 boxes among a total of 2500.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Represent children as indices into arrays, not as strings:

   ```
   childrenScores = [0] * 10
   gp1 = [2,6,9] # children who selected box 1
   ...
   gp5 = [1,4,7,9]

   boxes = [(0,gp1), (0,gp2), (1,gp3), (1,gp4), (0,gp5)]
   ```
2. Then, you can store `childrenScores` as a NumPy array and use advanced indexing:

   ```
   childrenScores = np.zeros(10, dtype=int)
   ...
   for box in boxes:
       if box[0]:
           childrenScores[box[1]] += 1 # NumPy advanced indexing
   ```

   This still involves a loop somewhere, but the loop is deep inside NumPy instead, which should provide a meaningful speedup.

Comment: Unfortunately, I also have to know some information about children. Suppose, for example, their age and size. So, my real variables are in the form "1_12_170" (number_age_size). That's what I keep them in the form of string and I can not convert them into numbers.

Comment: @user2737736, you can convert them to numbers and have those be the index of a structure where additional information is stored (the id of a database table, for instance).

Comment: @user2737736: in this case, store the information about their age and size in a separate structure (e.g. a list of `Children` instances), again indexed by their ID.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida Yes, the search time in the database is negligible contrary to what I feared. However, I am facing a strange problem. Numpy is much faster when each box is chosen by the same number of children. But if the number varies, Numpy is worse than the pure Python, it doesn't make sense! You can test this by yourself, [this code](http://pastebin.com/c298UtjS) produces [good result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/If9Y8.png). Simply [add a randrange line 10](http://pastebin.com/5SxjCUPR), and [that](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fu6fu.png) is what it gives. It's slower with NumPy, I don't understand.

Comment: @user2737736: In the first case, you created a nice 2D NumPy array because every list had the same number of elements. In the second case, since the lists are not the same size, you created a 1D NumPy array of Python objects, where each object is a Python list. To fix this, you should simply make a list of 1D NumPy arrays.

Comment: I understand better through you, thank you for bringing me for help!

Answer (score 2):

The only speed up that I can think of is to use numpy arrays and stream the sum operation.

```
children[child] += np.ones(len(children[child]))
```

You should benchmark the operation and see if that is too slow for your business case.

Answer (score 1):

**What I would do**

In the `gpX` lists don't save the "name of the child" (e.g. `"child_10"`) but save a reference to the child's number of points.

**How to do that**

Using the fact that lists are objects in python, you can:

1. Change the children dict to look like: `children = {"child_0": [0], "child_1": [0], ...}` and so on.
2. When you assign to group, don't assign the *key* but assign the *value* (e.g. `gp1.append(children["child_0"])`).
3. The loop should then look like: `for child in box[1]: child[0]+=1`. This **WILL** update the `children` dict.

EDIT:

**Why this is faster**:
Because you leave out the part where you search for `children[child]`, which might be costly.

This technique works because by storing the totals in a mutable type, and appending those values to the group lists, both the dict value and each box's list value will point to the same list entries, and changing one will change the other.

Comment: This is a very clever technique!  My only caveat to the OP would be that it's usually best to save optimization until the end, when you can figure out what parts of your code are unacceptably slow.  Time spent optimizing a portion of code that runs acceptably fast is time wasted.

Comment: I would be interested to see if `child[0]` is actually faster than `children[name]`. Accessing a list with only one element will be fast, but theoretically dictionary lookups are supposed to perform equally regardless of the dictionary's size.

Answer (score 1):

Two general points:

(1) Based on what you've told us, there's **no reason to focus your energy on minor performance optimizations**. Your time would be better spent thinking about ways to make your data structures less awkward and more communicative. A bunch of interrelated dicts, lists, and tuples quickly becomes difficult to maintain. For an alternative, see the example below.

(2) As the game designer, you understand that events follow a certain sequence: *first* the kids select their boxes, and *later* they discover whether they get points for them. But you don't have to implement it that way. **A kid can choose a box and get points (or not) immediately**. If there's a need to preserve the child's ignorance about such outcomes, the parts of your algorithm that depend on such ignorance can enforce that veil of secrecy as needed. The upshot: there is no need for a box to loop through its children, awarding points to each one; instead, award the points immediately to kids as boxes are selected.

```
import random

class Box(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.prize = random.randint(0,1)

class Child(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.boxes = []
        self.score = 0
        self._score = 0

    def choose(self, n, boxes):
        bs = random.sample(boxes, n)
        for b in bs:
            self.boxes.append(b)
            self._score += b.prize

    def reveal_score(self):
        self.score = self._score

boxes = [Box(i) for i in range(5)]
kids = [Child(i) for i in range(10)]

for k in kids:
    k.choose(3, boxes)

# Later in the game ...
for k in kids:
    k.reveal_score()
    print (k.name, k.score), '=>', [(b.name, b.prize) for b in k.boxes]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way or another, you're going to be looping over the children, and your answer appears to avoid looping over children who don't get any points.

It might be slightly faster to use filter or itertools.ifilter to pick the boxes that have something in them:

```
import itertools

...

for box in itertools.ifilter(lambda x: x[0], boxes):
    for child in box[1]
        children[child] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to immediately print the number of points for *every* child, you could calculate it on demand, thus saving time. This could help if you only need to query a child every now and then for how many points it has. You can cache each result as you obtain is so you don't go about calculating it again the next time you need it.

Firstly, you'll need to know which groups a child belongs to. We'll store this information as map we'll call childToGroupsMap, which will map each child to an array holding the boxes it belongs to, like so:

```
childToGroupsMap = {}
for child in children:
    childToGroupsMap[child[0]] = []
for box in boxes:
    for child in box[1]:
        if (box[1] not in childToGroupsMap[child]):
            childToGroupsMap[child].append(box[1])
```

This constructs the reverse map from children to boxes.

It'll also help to have a map from each box to a boolean representing whether it's been opened:

```
boxToOpenedMap = {}
for box in boxes:
    boxToOpenedMap[box[1]] = box[0]
```

Now, when someone queries how many points a child has, you can go through each of the boxes it belongs to (using `childToGroupsMap`, of course), and simply count how many of those boxes have been mapped to `1` in the map `boxes`:

```
def countBoxesForChild(child):
    points = 0
    for box in childToGroupsMap[child]
        if boxToOpenedMap[box] == 1:
            points += 1
    return points
```

To make this better, you can *cache* the resulting number of points. Make a map like so:

```
childToPointsCalculated = {}
for child in children:
    childToPointsCalculated[child[0]] = -1
```

Where the `-1` denotes that we don't yet know how many points this child has.

Finally, you can modify your `countBoxesForChild` function to exploit the cache:

```
def countBoxesForChild(child):
    if childToPointsCalculated[child] != -1
        return childToPointsCalculated[child]

    points = 0
    for box in childToGroupsMap[child]
        if boxToOpenedMap[box] == 1:
            points += 1
    childToPointsCalculated[child] = points
    return points
```

Comment: `++` is not legal in Python.

Comment: @nneonneo, thanks!, I've been juggling between languages a lot lately.